# Running Gulp command from terminal

Tags: wordpress, sass, gulp

I'm designing a Wordpress theme for the first time on a MAMP environment using an online tutorial.

I'm a newbie to Gulp and SASS and I'm trying to run/execute Gulp from  a folder on my Mac, but cannot seem to get the command right in terminal.

I have run and installed Gulp successfully, but cannot get the next part of the process (the tutorial only gives instructions for Windows).

I know I have to execute a "run" command on the , but I keep getting it wrong.

In short, what should a "run" or "execute" file command look like in Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal, what commands have you run so far.
Check for node, npm, npx and gulp
A quick way to check if they are installed is using these commands.

```
node --version

npm --version

npx --version
```

Then have you gulpfile.js file? If not run this command

```
npx -p touch nodetouch gulpfile.js
```

Then add your SASS commands in the file.

e.g

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

To run gulp, make sure you are within the directory which has the gulpfile.js.

```
gulp
```

Here is a quick start on getting you going with Gulp on terminal in mac.
https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start

Hope that helps.